# How do I Populate a Result View Column with Value from Stored Proc in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Edit: HAS to be a stored proc, **NOT a function**, sorry!

I have a table:

```
TABLE: dbo.Numbers 
Number_ID | Number
1         | 0
2         | 1
3         | 2
4         | 3
5         | 4
6         | 5
7         | 6     
8         | 7
```

I want the following output (**as a View**):

```
Number_ID | ModifiedNumber
1         | lol the num is 0
2         | lol the num is 1
3         | lol the num is 2
4         | lol the num is 3
5         | lol the num is 4
6         | lol the num is 5
7         | lol the num is 6      
8         | lol the num is 7
```

I have a stored procedure to do this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UselessStoredProc @inputNum int
AS
SELECT 'lol my number is: ' + CONVERT(varchar(max), @inputNum)
GO

--TEST
EXEC dbo.UselessStoredProc @inputNum=2;
```

My end goal is to populate the`ModifiedNumber` col via stored proc, e.g.:

```
SELECT Number_ID, EXEC UselessStoredProc @inputNum = Number_ID  as ModifiedNumber
FROM [TestDb].[dbo].[Numbers]
```

Obviously this doesn't work. How do I accomplish this.

P.S. Please don't tell me "just do:

```
SELECT Number_ID, 'lol my number is: ' + CONVERT(varchar(max), Number_ID) as ModifiedNumber
FROM [TestDb].[dbo].[Numbers]
```

"

I am well aware I can do that - this is obviously an example, the real code is much more complicated and requires a **STORED PROCEDURE**. Note, I intentionally return a string from the sample stored proc - I need complex values, not just `int`.

Edit:

> SQL Server 2012
>
> Functions are NOT an option. I apologize for the confusion. My "function" needs to call built in Stored Procs, and functions can't do that.

Edit 2: The reason I need an SP, rather than a function, is because I need to dynamically find the primary key of some table, so I need to use dynamic SQL. I thought this was too much info, but looks like it's necessary:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT @Data_Table_Key = COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), ''IsPrimaryKey'') = 1 AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @Data_Table_Name + ''''
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@Data_Table_Key varchar(200) OUTPUT', @Data_Table_Key OUTPUT
```

Edit: In the end, I was trying to do something that can't be done with [openrowset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql), which is a dirty, dirty hack. I ended up writing a stored proc which writes to a table every 5 mins, and the third-party software uses that table. I appreciate all the help. I accepted the answer which helped me most, but the while-loop answer was also helpful and got me what I need, albeit at unacceptable performance.

Comment: in sql, you can add breaking points, hover over the variable or quick watch it

Comment: Which DBMS is this?

Comment: Does it have to be a stored procedure or is a function possible?

Comment: Let me guess, function is not possible because you want to use DML(update/delete/insert) or even dynamic SQL. In other words, you cannot mutate table when doing `SELECT`. This simply won't work in a way you propose: `SELECT ..., EXEC stored_procedure FROM ...`. So please describe your real problem instead of creating [XYProblem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @XYProblem: Absolutely correct, I need to select a table's primary key column's name, i.e. `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT @Data_Table_Key = COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), ''IsPrimaryKey'') = 1 AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @Data_Table_Name + ''''
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@Data_Table_Key varchar(200) OUTPUT', @Data_Table_Key OUTPUT`  So, looks like it's the while loop for me.

Comment: Can't you simply pass the name of the 'input table' to the stored procedure and have the store procedure work on the entire set instead of passing just the 1 value in the @inputNum parameter? In the end you then let the stored procedure output everything.

Comment: @deroby I have to get a different table name for each row. Basically, we have user-created forms that can save to any table in the db (please ignore security for now, we know), so I need to get data out of whichever table the form saved to for that particular row/answer.

Comment: OK. And all the tables have different layout etc I presume, so you need to build code dynamically to get the right fields etc for each table. I'd suggest to simply do all that in the 1 stored procedure and have that one return the data. Where does the view come into play? Views have a fixed "layout", so you can't adjust the fields in the view according to whatever table the data might be coming out of.

Comment: I need a view for third-party reporting software, unfortunately.

Comment: Understandably, as the reporting software probably expects a fixed layout of the data being sent to it. Is the plan for the stored procedure to first 'massage' the data into a fixed format and then have that /uploaded/ via the view? If so, you're probably better of by preparing the data in some overnight process and have it ready by the time the reporting software asks for it. If your data needs to be 'realtime' then I don't see how the reporting-software will be able to trigger the stored procedure that will do the 'massaging' =(

Comment: IMHO,you ask this question on "Jan 11" and still not able to ask the question properly.Instead you should have ask your main problem itself here delete rest.After finding pk of each table what you gonna do with it etc etc.Don't take it other wise,you are wrong in the first place.

Comment: there is no way to do exactly what you wanted. The only sensible way is to modify your `UselessStoredProc ` and incorporate the base table `Numbers`in it and do it as a set base. Other than that is to use a loop and loop for each rows in `Numbers` table

Comment: @VSO, please, help us to help you. If you've came across a function, and that didn't work because of SQL UDFs limitations (such as dynamic SQL), please, at least show us what would that UDF be, so we may have a solid starting point. Besides... I'm posting an answer based on `... COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA...` from you latest edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on

> Edit 2: The reason I need an SP, rather than a function, is because I need to dynamically find the primary key of some table, so I need to use dynamic SQL. I thought this was too much info, but looks like it's necessary:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT @Data_Table_Key = COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + ''.'' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), ''IsPrimaryKey'') = 1 AND TABLE_NAME = ''' + @Data_Table_Name + ''''
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@Data_Table_Key varchar(200) OUTPUT', @Data_Table_Key OUTPUT
```

I'm confused. Why would you do this in dynamic SQL in the first place.

You can just as well do:

```
SELECT @Data_Table_Key = COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
 WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1 
  AND TABLE_NAME = @Data_Table_Name
```

and end up with the same result in your `@Data_Table_Key` variable.

That said, your approach will give you 'incomplete' results whenever you try to fetch the PK columns from a table that has multiple fields in the primary key. No telling which one you'll get, but it will be just one of them (usually the last one, but you can't count on it!).

Some example code:

```
CREATE TABLE t_test_multiple_pk_fields ( key1 int NOT NULL,
                                         key2 int NOT NULL,
                                            constraint pk_test PRIMARY KEY (key1, key2),
                                         value1 int,
                                         value2 int)

DECLARE @Data_Table_Name sysname,
        @Data_Table_Key  sysname

SELECT @Data_Table_Name = 't_test_multiple_pk_fields'

SELECT Data_Table_Key = COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
 WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1 
  AND TABLE_NAME = @Data_Table_Name 

SELECT @Data_Table_Key = COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
 WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA + '.' + QUOTENAME(CONSTRAINT_NAME)), 'IsPrimaryKey') = 1 
  AND TABLE_NAME = @Data_Table_Name 

SELECT @Data_Table_Key
```

Comment: The "why would you do this dynamically" part gives me something to think about - thanks.

Comment: @VSO this was my thought too. Why the need for dynamic sql?  if you wanted to get the actual value of a row of a dynamically chosen key column then that would be different, but that doesn't appear to be the case in your example.  There is only 1 way I know how to call a stored procedure in the manner you want and that would be to use SQL CLR and have a CLR scalar function call the procedure.  That would be horrible and inefficient!

Comment: @VSO Also if it has to be dynamic.  Then think though the issue differently.  Not as a per row operation but as a batch.  So your first step could be to create the dynamic SQL for every row at one and then execute all of it in the sp or something but cross applying per row isn't a good idea here

Answer (score 2):

Processing your data [RBAR](https://sqlstudies.com/2016/08/17/rbar-vs-batch/) is to be avoided wherever possible as SQL Server is designed for batch processing, but I'm working on the assumption that you don't have a choice in the matter. With that assumption in mind, this should achieve what you're after:

```
-- Generate some dummy data

Declare @Numbers Table
(
    Number_ID int primary key,
    Number varchar(100)
)

;with cte as
(
    select 1 [Value]
    union all
    select value+1 from cte where (value+1) < 9
)
insert into @Numbers(Number_ID, number)
select value, convert(varchar(100), value-1) from cte

-- Process the records, one at a time

declare @id int=0
declare @result table (value varchar(100))
while (1=1)
begin
    -- Get the ID of the next record for processing
    select @id=min(number_id) from @numbers where number_id>@id
    if (@id is null)
        break

    -- Call the useless stored procedure and dump the results into a temp table (table layout must match that of the resultset from the SP)
    insert into @result(value)
    exec UselessStoredProc @id

    -- Copy the value from the temp table to the appropriate record in your numbers table
    update n set Number=r.value
    from @numbers n
    cross join @result r
    where n.Number_ID=@id

    -- Clear out the temp table, ready for your next value
    delete from @result
end

-- Show the results
select * from @Numbers
```

I'm using a WHILE loop here to iterate through your numbers table as it's considerably more efficient (or should I say less inefficient) that a CURSOR.

Again, if there's any way you can avoid the RBAR pattern then I'd go for it.

Comment: @Pete: Sadly, your assumption that a "poor man's cursor" as it is called is "considerably more efficient" is a myth. When doing cursors properly they'll outperform this approach easily. I've inherited sufficient code over time to get to realize that they're not really faster but definitely are much less easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: @deroby - and here we have one of the great joys of software development: there is no "one right answer" to any particular problem, just a million different opinions as to what the wrong one is. I think it's fair to say that any approach relying on RBAR is wrong - it's just not how SQL DBs are designed to work. As far as CURSOR vs WHERE, that depends on the schema you're working with. Personally I've inherited reams of code that's overly reliant on CURSORS and had to re-do most of it. Where I haven't been able to convert to SET-based I've found that WHERE is more maintainable and performant.

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes no sense, just to show an option here is a way using [table type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql) parameter.

create a table type called `udtNumbers`. This will be used to pass the numbers as input parameter to procedure. Most importantly avoids *RBAR*

```
create type udtNumbers(Number_ID int, Number int)
```

alter the procedure to accept table type as input parameter.

```
Alter PROCEDURE dbo.UselessStoredProc @inputNum udtNumbers READONLY
AS
SELECT Number_ID, 'lol my number is: ' + CONVERT(varchar(max), Number)
from @inputNum
GO
```

now call the procedure

```
Declare @inputNum udtNumbers

insert into @inputNum(Number_ID, Number)
select Number_ID, Number
from dbo.Numbers

exec dbo.UselessStoredProc @inputNum
```

Hope this helps you in some way to solve your real world problem

Answer (score 1):

Functions can definitely be used in views. You don't say how the number should be modified, other than showing it decremented by 1. That being said the function should be able to accomplish whatever logic you want. Simplistically then this would be (Using AdventureWorks tables)...

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.UselessFunction1 
go
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UselessFunction1(@inputnum int)
RETURNS varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @outputString varchar(30)
    SELECT @outputString = 'lol my number is  ' + CAST(@inputnum-1 AS varchar(10))
    RETURN @outputString
END
GO
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.UselessView1
go
CREATE VIEW dbo.UselessView1 AS
SELECT Name,dbo.UselessFunction1(pc.ProductCategoryID) AS Number_ID
FROM Production.ProductCategory AS pc
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.UselessView1 AS uv;
```

Scalar functions of course are not ideal from a perrformance perspective so if you can get away with a single query to perform whatever logic UselessStoredProc is performing, an Inline Table Valued Function would be better, e.g....

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.UselessFunction2
go 
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UselessFunction2(@inputnum int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
        SELECT 'lol my number is  ' + CAST(@inputnum-1 AS varchar(10)) AS Number_ID
        )
GO
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.UselessView2
go
CREATE VIEW dbo.UselessView2 AS
SELECT Name,x.Number_ID
FROM Production.ProductCategory AS pc
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Number_ID FROM dbo.UselessFunction2(pc.ProductCategoryID)) x
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.UselessView1 AS uv;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to make a 'gigantic' view upfront that combines all the possible tables the application might want to see.

e.g. something along the lines of

```
CREATE TABLE t_tableA (keyA int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, valueA1 varchar(10), valueA2 datetime)
CREATE TABLE t_tableB (keyB int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, valueB1 int, valueB2 varchar(500), valueB3 int)

GO
CREATE VIEW v_all_tables
AS
SELECT table_name = 't_tableA', table_key = keyA, table_value = Convert(nvarchar(max), valueA1) + ' - ' + Convert(nvarchar(max), valueA2)
  FROM t_tableA

UNION ALL 

SELECT table_name = 't_tableB', table_key = keyB, table_value = '[' + Convert(nvarchar(max), valueB1) + '] ' + Convert(nvarchar(max), valueB2) + ' = ' + Convert(nvarchar(max), valueB3)
  FROM t_tableB

GO

SELECT * FROM v_all_tables WHERE table_name = 't_tableA'
```

It's a view, it would be 'realtime' and you can easily filter out the table you need. This could work for hundreds of tables. 
However, whenever you add a new table to the database you'll need to update the view to include it!
Instead of writing a stored procedure that fetches the data you might then want to write a stored procedure that drops/creates the view and run it every night or whenever a new table is added.